# Ember and HTML5 contenteditable property

Tags: html, ember.js

I just found out about the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) spec in HTML5. Basically, it allows any html element to be editable when you click on it, just by setting that property to true. For example:

```
<p contenteditable=true>Editable content</p>
```

would be editablewhen you clicked on it.

Unfortunately this doesn't notify Ember about the change Ember objects, so Ember doesn't know that the value has been changed.

I'm not sure how bindings work, but would this be possible to implement somehow?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kkzrb/3/) to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: I tried to implement this with a view, action, helper, etc and failed. I would use Gevious' method since it's still quite simple and will have wider browser support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the contrary, using `contenteditable` is both perfectly possible and a great approach to certain use cases in which you wish to implement input areas that resize automatically etc.

Ember.js already contains a view class for `<input>` elements, but none for `<div>` elements with `contenteditable` set to `true`. The key here is to bind to the HTML content of the div and expose a `value` property just like `Ember.TextField` has it.

I've covered this in a blog post which can be found here: http://www.kaspertidemann.com/handling-contenteditable-in-ember-js-via-app-contenteditableview/

The blog post boils down to the introduction of `App.ContenteditableView`, the source of which can be found here: https://github.com/KasperTidemann/ember-contenteditable-view

I hope this helps!

Comment: Blogpost resource does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the html5 `contenteditable`, since, like you said, you it doesn't talk with ember.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kkzrb/8/) to see how I would do it in ember. It doesn't have the coolness factor of contenteditable, but at least you know it'll work on all browsers.

Comment: Yeah, this would be one way of doing it and I may end up using it, but nevertheless, I want to know what it would take to make the _cool_ solution work :)

Comment: Yah, the containable is definitely a lot cooler. I'm sure it'll be standard practise in the near future

Comment: contenteditable appears to be already supported by a very wide range of browsers: http://caniuse.com/contenteditable