# Binding on view with dependency

Tags: data-binding, view, ember.js

I am using a view to bind data to a contentEditable `div` using the code found in the answer to this question: [Ember and HTML5 contenteditable property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080538/ember-and-html5-contenteditable-property)

I have a property `a.b.c` that I'm binding it to like so:

```
{{view App.ContenteditableView valueBinding="a.b.c"}}
```

This correctly updates `a.b.c` when I type in it, and it updates itself when I modify `a.b.c`. However, It does not update when I change `a` to a different object. That is, the text box needs to update when `a` or `b` changes, not just when `c` changes.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Ember already supports this if you properly use the built in setters.

if `a` extends Ember.Object `a.set('b', { c: 'asdf'})`  if `a` is a POJO `Ember.set(a, 'b', { c: 'asdf'})`.

Additionally using valueBinding isn't necessary, you can just write `value=a.b.c`

In the provided example I set the text box to `a.b.c`

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      a:{
        b:{
          c:'dog'
        }
      }
    };
  },
  actions:{
    change: function(){
      Em.set(this.currentModel, 'a', {b:{c:'fdasdf'}});
    }
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/toticame/1/edit

Comment: Hi Kingpin, thank you for your reply. However, I am seeing some strange behavior. I have the equivalent of this code: `{{view Ember.ContenteditableView value=a.b.c editable=true}} {{a.b.c}}`. When I do what you said, the `{{a.b.c}}` updates, but the contentEditable doesn't update. Also, if I add an observer like `x: function() { console.log('x') }.observes('a.b.c')`, this observer fires whenever I update `a.b.c` as expected, but the content editable doesn't update. What could be my problem?