# Component Attribute Binding is Rendering a String

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set up data binding for a component attr, and when I do so my property is returning the a string. I have a custom component class:

```
App.EditableTextComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['contenteditable'],

  isEditable: true
});
```

And, my handlebar template:

```
<span class="editable-text" {{bind-attr contenteditable=isEditable}}>{{content}}</span>
```

Whenever I render this template, if isEditable is true, it will render: `contenteditable="contenteditable"` rather than `contenteditable` like shown in the example here http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/.

I can get this example to work if I set my isEditable property to a string of "true", but this doesn't seem right, as it should be a boolean for use in other places. How do I get this data binding to work without setting the property to a string?

Comment: It lies, it isn't properly supported yet in Ember, you can hack it in, but it needs some actual internals fixed for it to work completely and properly.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127862/binding-on-view-with-dependency/24131321#24131321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App.EditableTextComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['contenteditable'],

  isEditable: true,

  contenteditable: function() {
    return this.get('isEditable') ? 'true' : 'false';
  }.property('isEditable')
});
```

Usage:

```
{{editable-text isEditable=true}}
{{editable-text isEditable=false}}
```